# Get Incoming call number in Android not working for Android Pie(9.0)

Tags: android, phone-call, incoming-call

This is the code I used to do my work, but unfortunately **It doesn't work for my device with Android Pie(9.0)**. But **It works for device with Android Naugat(7.0)**. I already enabled the phone permission for the app using device App Settings. Can you give me a solution for this?

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                String phoneNo = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Got A Call From " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you register your receiver?By code?

Comment: @Afshin
public void register(View v){

        IntentFilter filter  = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");

        MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();

        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

Comment: add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
permission  for android P and above

Comment: did you find any solution for this?